# SQL: Find difference between rows where a column value matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

sorry if my title doesn't properly describe what task I'm trying to perform.

For a university project, I have received the access logs of a website, I have discarded the unneeded columns and condensed it down to this:

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════════╦════════════════╗
║ accessid ║ date_time_in_seconds ║ yg_requester_id ║ referent_id ║ referent_docid ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╣
║     2449 ║        2009011621830 ║           32276 ║       12648 ║              1 ║
║     2776 ║        2009011622726 ║           76360 ║       11070 ║              1 ║
║     2804 ║        2009011622783 ║           32276 ║       13845 ║              1 ║
║     2894 ║        2009011623025 ║           32276 ║        7222 ║              1 ║
║     2895 ║        2009011623037 ║           32276 ║        1530 ║              1 ║
║     3000 ║        2009011623406 ║           32276 ║        3728 ║              1 ║
║     3019 ║        2009011623497 ║          520060 ║       10356 ║              1 ║
║     3245 ║        2009011625780 ║          300841 ║        4607 ║              1 ║
║     3274 ║        2009011628309 ║          532664 ║       14377 ║              1 ║
║     3275 ║        2009011628420 ║          532664 ║        9097 ║              1 ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Originally the time and datestamps were in seperate columns per unit of measurement (year, month, day, hour, minute, second) and for the purposes of easier calculation, I have consolidated them into date_time_in_seconds which has the format

```
[0000][00][00][00000]
[YEAR][MONTH][DAY][Number of Seconds since 00:00]
```

accessid is the table entry ID, yg_requester_id is the unique id of the website visitor, referent_id is the ID of the web site article they read, referent_docid denotes the type of article, however is not needed in this task.

Basically, I would like to be able to find the time difference since the last different referent_id was accessed by the same yg_requester_id.
So for instance, looking at this section of rows from the above table:

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════════╦════════════════╗
║ accessid ║ date_time_in_seconds ║ yg_requester_id ║ referent_id ║ referent_docid ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╣
║     2449 ║        2009011621830 ║           32276 ║       12648 ║              1 ║
║     2776 ║        2009011622726 ║           76360 ║       11070 ║              1 ║
║     2804 ║        2009011622783 ║           32276 ║       13845 ║              1 ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════════╩════════════════╝
```

yg_requester_id 32276 accessed the article with id **12648** at ***06:03:50*** (*21830* seconds after midnight) on the 16th of January 2009. They then accessed the article with id **13845** at ***06:19:43*** (*22783* seconds after midnight)  on the 16th January 2009. So it is safe to assume that the user read the first article (id **12648**) for about 15 minutes and 50 seconds

What I would like to find is that time difference between the articles accessed by the same user. Consecutive articles read by a user may not have consecutive accessid's (although it will always increment). I would also like to limit the time read to about an hour as the task is to filter out records where the time read is *under* a variable number of minutes (15 for instance).

Thanks in advance, let me know if any more information is needed

Comment: First of all, don't MAKE UP a new convention to store time just for the sake of it. You can use unix seconds from 1970, or you could store it as a proper datetime field; out of the original component fields.

Comment: Thanks, I just merged the date/time measurements in that way as I thought it would be easier to calculate. I still have the original data and will convert it to a proper datetime datatype.

Comment: What do you do with the last access, do you compare that against GetDate() for the duration?

Comment: If there is a large time difference (say an hour or more) then the difference will be capped at an hour. I am trying to isolate the the entries where the following article was accessed 15 minutes or less since the previous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use ROW_NUMBER partitioning the resultset by yg_requester_id and ordering it by either accessid or datetime (supposing you are going to change your date_time_in_seconds column into a regular datetime column, as suggested in the comments.
Then I would join the resultset with itself by requester and to the previous record, and get the difference.

Let me try to write the query without having the proper data:

```
SELECT X1.yg_requester_id, DATEDIFF(SECOND, X1.NewDateTimeField, X2.NewDateTimeField) AS TimeDifferenceInSeconds, X1.referent_id AS NewArticle, X2.referent_id AS FormerArticle
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY yg_requester_id ORDER BY NewDateTimeField DESC) AS Position, NewDateTimeField, yg_requester_id, referent_id
FROM YourTable

) X1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY yg_requester_id ORDER BY NewDateTimeField DESC) AS Position, NewDateTimeField, yg_requester_id, referent_id
FROM YourTable  
) X2 ON X2.yg_requester_id = X1.yg_requester_id AND X2.Position = X1.Position - 1
```

Comment: @Edward You are welcome. Could you please mark the answer as the valid one? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This query should retrieve the requestor, referent and the time difference in seconds that is taken by the requestor on the referent:

```
select abc.A_requestor as requestor_id,abc.B_refer as referent_id,abc.A_datetime-abc.B_datetime as time_difference   from 
(select a.accessid as A_accessid ,b.accessid as B_accessid,
a.yg_requestor_id as A_requestor,a.date_time_in_seconds as A_datetime,a.referent_id as A_refer,
b.yg_requestor_id as B_requestor,b.date_time_in_seconds as B_datetime,b.referent_id as B_refer
from weblog a
inner join weblog b
on a.yg_requestor_id = b.yg_requestor_id
and a.date_time_in_seconds > b.date_time_in_seconds
and a.referent_id != b.referent_id) abc

inner join 

(select cte.B_accessid,min(cte.A_accessid) as C_accessid from
(select a.accessid as A_accessid ,b.accessid as B_accessid,
a.yg_requestor_id as A_requestor,a.date_time_in_seconds as A_datetime,a.referent_id as A_refer,
b.yg_requestor_id as B_requestor,b.date_time_in_seconds as B_datetime,b.referent_id as B_refer
from weblog a
inner join weblog b
on a.yg_requestor_id = b.yg_requestor_id
and a.date_time_in_seconds > b.date_time_in_seconds
and a.referent_id != b.referent_id) cte 
group by cte.B_accessid ) xyz

on xyz.B_accessid = abc.B_accessid and xyz.C_accessid = abc.A_accessid
```